# How can i debug this ajax script for IE?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I have and an AJAX script in a page that works just fine with no bugs in firefoex, but IE6 loads the page with an ugly error icon on the status bar.  What is the best way i can go about fixing/debugging this?

Here is the error report:

[image]

I have checked line 323 many times Here is the function:

```
function checkAvailability(){

   var card_select  = document.getElementById('card_select').value;
   var price_select = document.getElementById('price_select').value;
   var num_of_cards = document.getElementById('num_of_cards').value;
   var url = 'checkAvailability.php?cardName=' + card_select + '&value=' + price_select + '&amount=' + num_of_cards;

   var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject)
            {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Your browser does not support XMLHTTP!");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =    function()
                                            {
                                                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.responseText) /**** line 323 ****/
                                                {
                                                    document.getElementById('submit_button').className      = 'hidden';
                                                    document.getElementById('div_error_massage').className  = 'anounce_div';
                                                    document.getElementById('error_massage').innerHTML      = xmlhttp.responseText;
                                                    document.getElementById('num_of_cards').className       = 'red_inputs';
                                                }
                                                else if(isNaN(num_of_cards))
                                                {
                                                    document.getElementById('submit_button').className      = 'hidden';
                                                    document.getElementById('num_of_cards').className       = 'red_inputs';
                                                    document.getElementById('div_error_massage').className  = 'hidden';

                                                }
                                                else if(num_of_cards != "" && !xmlhttp.responseText) 
                                                {
                                                    document.getElementById('submit_button').className      = '';
                                                    document.getElementById('error_massage').innerHTML      = 'Total: $' + document.getElementById('price_select').value * document.getElementById('num_of_cards').value  + '.00';
                                                    document.getElementById('div_error_massage').className  = 'anounce_div';

                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    document.getElementById('submit_button').className      = 'hidden';
                                                    document.getElementById('num_of_cards').className       = 'red_inputs';
                                                }
                                            }




            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);

}
```

Comment: You might want to check for (xmlhttp.status == 200) in addition to checking the readyState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE, you can try the old [script debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2f465be0-94fd-4569-b3c4-dffdf19ccd99&displaylang=en) or [Visual Web Developer Express](http://www.berniecode.com/blog/2007/03/08/how-to-debug-javascript-with-visual-web-developer-express/). When the error throws, enter the debugger and examine `xmlhttp`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to outis' answer, if you want to control where you jump in with the debugger, use Javascript's `debugger` keyword, which acts like a breakpoint. When the line with `debugger;` is hit, in IE you will get a prompt (if debugging is enabled in IE, check your Internet Options) to launch the debugger, starting at that line. In Firefox, the `debugger;` statement is picked up by Firebug as a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read !xmlhttp.responseText when the readyState is not 4

Try removing that line and see if IE runs.

Answer (score 0):

A great Javascript debugger for IE comes with MS Office.

A quick google shows this as a howto: http://www.jonathanboutelle.com/mt/archives/2006/01/howto_debug_jav.html